# jQuery <input> element problem with onclick attribute

Tags: jquery

I want an  element with an onclick attribute. When I use jQuery, it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
$("h1").append($("<input>", {type: "text", onclick: "alert();"}));
```

The following code **does** work:

```
<input type="text" onclick="alert();"></input>
```

Comment: [Works in Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k5t4j/); and works in [Firefox 5, if the `alert()` is alerting *something*](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k5t4j/1/).

Comment: on this sort of debugging, I always specify `alert("click")`, because I assumed it needed a string :)

Comment: Hum. Doesn't work on the last version of Chrome for me!

Comment: how about `append($('<input type="text" onclick="alert();">'));` instead?

Comment: Yep, that works. But it still puzzles me as to why my first method fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you really *don't* want the `onclick` attribute, you want to use jQuery's `click` event. Setting the `onclick` attribute works in most browsers, but it wouldn't be taking advantage of jQuery's normalized events and cross-browser support.

Also, you're not using the jQuery factory method correctly, the second argument it takes is the context for the selector, or, in the case where you're creating html, the owner document for the element to be created in. You really should spend some time reading through the [api](http://api.jquery.com/).

You can chain most methods in jQuery, so the "jQuery way" of doing what you want is:

```
$('<input>').attr('type', 'text').click(function(){alert();}).appendTo('h1');
```

Comment: @rabudde, with the exception that i explained *why*, and that I used a different context for appending the element.

Comment: @zzzzBov for sure, but the result is the same ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
$("h1").append($("<input>").attr("type","text").click(function(){alert()}));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$('h1').append('<input type="text">').find('input').live('click', function () {
    alert('bam');
});
```

EDIT: Yeah I noticed that David Thomas' comment was correct, just changing the alert to actually output something works fine.